# Why does the car drying towel I bought have a rough side and a soft side, can both sides be used for drying the car?

Tags: car, cleaning, paint-scratches

I bought this drying towel:

https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Microfibre-perfect-streak-free-vehicles-04512000/dp/B09NBSWQSY/

but I find that it has a soft side that can be used to dry the car body, but it has a rough side also. Can both sides be used to dry the car body? The rough side seems that it can cause harm to the paint. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I have one that is microfiber on one side and a nylon mesh on the other which is there to help scrub off bugs and other difficult stuff.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @jwh20 but will using the nylon side hurt/ruin the paint?

Comment: I have never had that happen but you should test it on an inconspicuous area first.

Comment: If the accompanying literature doesn't spell out rough/soft side use and doesn't have a nylon mesh on one side, it may be just how it's manufactured to create the loops on both sides. Old school (pre microfiber) chamois cloths were made from leather and absorbs water readily once soaked. Expensive and replaced with microfiber cloths with better absorption without scratching fine paint. Washing after each use will remove any  embedded dirt to prevent scratching when used again.

Comment: Have you tried using the rough side for initial drying of really wet areas and then pull the smooth side across surfaces like a chamois for final drying?